# How can I optimize my pagination code?

Tags: javascript, pagination

I'm building a page in [LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc) this page consist of a table, you can search, sort and paginate with this table.

[image]

When the first element is selected:
[image]

when the last element is selected:
[image]

When the middle element is selected:
[image]

Here's pagination HTML code:

```
<div class="pageButtons">
        <template if:true={buttons} for:each={buttons} for:item="button" for:index="index">
            <template if:true={button.isVisible}>
                <lightning-button key={button.value} variant="Neutral" if:true={button.isVisible} disabled={button.isDisabled} label={button.value} class="pageButton" onclick={paginate}></lightning-button>
            </template>
            <template if:true={button.isPlaceHolder}>
                <lightning-formatted-rich-text key={button.value} value="..."></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
            </template>
        </template>
    </div>
```

Here's the JS code:

```
//For initial load
const getButtonData = (pageSize) => {
    pageSize = pageSize + 1;
    let buttons = [];
    buttons.push(add('First', true, true, false));
    buttons.push(add('Previous', true, true, false));
    for (let i = 1; i <= pageSize; i++) {
        if (pageSize > 10) {
            if (i < 6) {
                buttons.push(add(i, i == 1 ? true : false, true, false));
            }
            else if (pageSize >= 6 && i == 6) {
                buttons.push(add(i, i == 1 ? true : false, pageSize > 6 ? false : true, pageSize > 6 ? true : false));
            }
            else if (i == pageSize) {
                buttons.push(add(i, false, true, false));
            }
        }
        else {
            buttons.push(add(i, i == 1 ? true : false, true, false));
        }
    }
    buttons.push(add('Next', false, true, false));
    buttons.push(add('Last', false, true, false));
    return buttons;
}

//For onclick of buttons
const getButtonDataByPage = (pageSize, currentPage) => {
    pageSize = pageSize + 1;
    let buttons = [];
    let isFirstPrev = currentPage == 1 ? true : false;
    buttons.push(add('First', isFirstPrev, true, false));
    buttons.push(add('Previous', isFirstPrev, true, false));
    if (pageSize > 10) {
        for (const i of getNextElements(currentPage, pageSize)) {
            buttons.push(
                add(
                    i.value,
                    i.value == currentPage,
                    i.isEllipses ? false : true,
                    i.isEllipses
                )
            );
        }
    }
    else {
        for (let i = 1; i <= pageSize; i++) {
            buttons.push(add(i, i == currentPage ? true : false, true, false));
        }
    }
    let isNextLast = currentPage == pageSize ? true : false;
    buttons.push(add('Next', isNextLast, true, false));
    buttons.push(add('Last', isNextLast, true, false));
    return buttons;
}

function add(value, isDisabled, isVisible, isPlaceHolder) {
    return {
        value : value,
        isDisabled: isDisabled,
        isVisible : isVisible,
        isPlaceHolder : isPlaceHolder
    };
}

//To get the index array along with ellipses 
function getNextElements(currentPage, pageSize) {
    let index = [];
    // Is first element
    if (currentPage == 1) {
        for (let j = 1; j <= pageSize; j++) {
            if (j < 6) {
                index.push({value : j, isEllipses: false});
            }
            else if (pageSize >= 6 && j == 6) {
                index.push({value : j, isEllipses: true});
            }
            else if (j == pageSize) {
                index.push({value : j, isEllipses: false});
            }
        }
    }
    // Is last element
    else if (currentPage == pageSize) {
        let lastColumn = (pageSize) - 5;
        for (let j = 1; j <= pageSize ; j++) {
            if (j > lastColumn) {
                index.push({value : j, isEllipses: false});
            }
            else if (j == lastColumn) {
                index.push({value : j, isEllipses: true});
            }
            else if (j == 1) {
                index.push({value : j, isEllipses: false});
            }
        }
    }
    // Is middle element
    else if (currentPage !== 1 || currentPage !== pageSize) {
        let lastColumn = (pageSize) - 5;
        let isCloseToFirstElement = (1 + currentPage <= 6) ? true : false;
        let isCloseToLastElement = ((pageSize - currentPage) < 5) ? true : false;
        if (isCloseToFirstElement) {
            for (let j = 1; j <= pageSize; j++) {
                if (j < 6) {
                    index.push({value : j, isEllipses: false});
                }
                else if (pageSize >= 6 && j == 6) {
                    index.push({value : j, isEllipses: true});
                }
                else if (j == pageSize) {
                    index.push({value : j, isEllipses: false});
                }
            }
        }
        if (isCloseToLastElement) {
            for (let j = 1; j <= pageSize ; j++) {
                if (j > lastColumn) {
                    index.push({value : j, isEllipses: false});
                }
                else if (j == lastColumn) {
                    index.push({value : j, isEllipses: true});
                }
                else if (j == 1) {
                    index.push({value : j, isEllipses: false});
                }
            }
        }
        if (!isCloseToLastElement && !isCloseToFirstElement) {
            for (let i = 1; i <= pageSize; i++) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    index.push({value : 1, isEllipses: false});
                }
                else if ((i !== 1 && i !== pageSize) && i == currentPage) {
                    index.push({value : currentPage - 2, isEllipses: true});
                    index.push({value : currentPage - 1, isEllipses: false});
                    index.push({value : currentPage, isEllipses: false});
                    index.push({value : currentPage + 1, isEllipses: false});
                    index.push({value : currentPage + 2, isEllipses: true});
                }
                else if (i == pageSize) {
                    index.push({value : i, isEllipses: false});
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}

export {getButtonData, getButtonDataByPage};
```

I know the JS can be optimized a bit better I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. As is, the title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Method Names

The most method names do not describe what the method really does and what the method name implies.

- `getButtonData` let me imply that it returns information about one button
- `getButtonDataByPage` the same like `getButtonData`
- `add` implies that something gets added to a collection

In generell method names that start with `get` are known as [*getter*](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/java/getters-and-setters/) and that they return values of an object that has no or less computation. The methods you provide starts with `get` but relay heavily on computation and do not return just a value.

Names that would better fit are: `buildInitialButtonList`, `buildNavigatedButtonList` and `createButton`.

## Hard to Read

> ```java
> if (pageSize > 10) {
>    if (i < 6) {
>        buttons.push(add(i, i == 1 ? true : false, true, false));
>    }
>    else if (pageSize >= 6 && i == 6) {
>        buttons.push(add(i, i == 1 ? true : false, pageSize > 6 ? false : true, >pageSize > 6 ? true : false));
>    }
>    else if (i == pageSize) {
>        buttons.push(add(i, false, true, false));
>    }
> }
> ```

The code smells [*boolean flags*](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1392524) and [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) make your code hard to read an to maintain.

Imagine you want to show only 3 instead 6 buttons: Alone in this small snipped you have to touch the code 5 times and in the whole code you provide 12 times.

## Many Conditions

Beside the code smells you have many conditions. The 3 lines below contain 4 conditions:

> ```java
> else if (pageSize >= 6 && i == 6) {
>    buttons.push(add(i, i == 1 ? true : false, pageSize > 6 ? false : true, pageSize > 6 ? true : false));
> }
> ```

## Simplify Conditions

Some conditions follow the semantic of `condition ? true : false` which is the same as `condition`. For instance:

> ```java
> buttons.push(add(i, i == 1 ? true : false, pageSize > 6 ? false : true, pageSize > 6 ? true : false))
> ```

Is the same as

```java
buttons.push(add(i, i == 1, pageSize > 6, pageSize > 6))
```

## Useless Conditions

Let's analyze `getButtonData` and the same will be apply to `getButtonDataByPage`.

> ```java
> else if (... && i == 6) {
>    buttons.push(add(i, i == 1 ? true : false, ..., ...));
> }
> ```

We first check if `(i == 6)` and if this is true we check if `i == 1` which will always be false:

```java
else if (... && i == 6) {
    buttons.push(add(i, false, ..., ...));
}
```

---

> ```java
> if (pageSize > 10) {
>    if (...) {/* ... */}
>    else if (pageSize >= 6 && i == 6) {
>        buttons.push(add(..., ..., pageSize <= 6, pageSize > 6));
>    }
> }
> ```

First we make sure that `pageSize > 10` and than we check if `pageSize >= 6`, `pageSize <= 6` and `pageSize > 6`. Since we already know that `pageSize` is greater than 10 we can simplify to:

```java
if (pageSize > 10) {
    if (...) {/* ... */}
    else if (i == 6) {
        buttons.push(add(..., ..., true, true));
    }
}
```

---

After the simplification:

```java
for (let i = 1; i <= pageSize; i++) {
    if (pageSize > 10) {
        if (i < 6) {
            buttons.push(add(i, i == 1, true, false));
        }
        else if (i == 6) {
            buttons.push(add(i, false, true, true));
        }
        else if (i == pageSize) {
            buttons.push(add(i, false, true, false));
        }
    }
    else {
        buttons.push(add(i, i == 1, true, false));
    }
}
```

where `i == 1` can have its own branch:

```java
if (i === 1) {
    buttons.push(add(i, true, true, false))
} else if (pageSize > 10) {
    if (i < 6) {
        buttons.push(add(i, false, true, false));
    } else if (i === 6) {
        buttons.push(add(i, false, true, true));
    } else if (i === pageSize) {
        buttons.push(add(i, false, true, false));
    }
} else {
    buttons.push(add(i, false, true, false));
}
```

Since only the first 6 button gets rendered we do not need to check for `pageSize > 10`:

```java
if (i === 1) {
    buttons.push(add(i, true, true, false))
} else if (i < 6) {
    buttons.push(add(i, false, true, false));
} else if (i === 6) {
    buttons.push(add(i, false, true, true));
} else if (i === pageSize) {
    buttons.push(add(i, false, true, false));
}
```

and since the branch body of `i < 6` and `i === pageSize` are the same:

```java
if (i === 1) {
    buttons.push(add(i, true, true, false))
} else if (i < 6 || i === pageSize) {
    buttons.push(add(i, false, true, false));
} else if (i === 6) {
    buttons.push(add(i, false, true, true));
}
```

## Builder Pattern

To go away from all the boolean flags you could create a [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) and refactor the simplified version from above to something like:

```java
const firstButton = new ButtonBuilder().withValue(1).disabled().visible().noPlaceholder();
const placeholder = new ButtonBuilder().enabled().visible().placeholder();
const button = new ButtonBuilder().enabled().visible().noPlaceholder();
for (let i = 1; i <= pageSize; i++) {
    if (i === 1) {
        buttons.push(firstButton);
    } else if (i < 6 || i === pageSize) {
        buttons.push(button.withValue(i).build());
    } else if (i === 6) {
        buttons.push(placeholder.withValue(i).build());
    }
}
```

---

## The Algorithm

In your example, you can page through 50 buttons, of which only 6 are required to render. For each button click you have to loop 50 times to render 6 buttons again.

But actually you know directly which buttons are required to render without to loop 50 times. There are 3 cases:

- on the first to 5. button  : `1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 50`
- on button between 6. to 50.: `1, ... 6, [7], 8, ..., 50`
- on button 47. to 50.: `1, ... 47, 48, [49], 50`

some pseudo code:

```
function buildPagination(current) {
    if (current < 6) {
        const pagination =  [
            button(1),
            button(2),
            button(3),
            button(4),
            button(5),
            placeholder(),
            button(last),
        ];
        pagination[current].disable();
        return pagination;
    }

    if (current > (last - 4)) {
        const pagination = [
            button(1),
            placeholder(),
            button(last - 4),
            button(last - 3),
            button(last - 2),
            button(last - 1),
            button(last),
        ];
        pagination[current].disable();
        return pagination;
    }

    return [
        button(1),
        placeholder(),
        button(current - 1),
        button(current).disable(),
        button(current + 1),
        placeholder(),
        button(last),
    ];
}
```